# Can't call WebAssembly Js API from ReactJs Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webassembly

Calling the WebAssembly API in an HTML file works perfectly,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      ...
          WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
       ...

   </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

However, calling it in a React Component, when running 'npm start' at the root of my react-app, results in this error:

```
'WebAssembly' is not defined  no-undef
```

---

```
import React from 'react';

export default class WasmContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.func = this.func.bind(this);
    }

    func(){
            ...
        WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
            ...

        return "...";
    }

    render() {
        return (<p>{this.func()}</p>)
    }
}
```

I want to run a `.wasm` file from a React Component and this is blocking me.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `WebAssembly` in your React component is not defined

Comment: import it: `import WebAssembly from 'web-assembly'`

Comment: Are you referring to this package: [web-assembly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-assembly) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very much like a linting error. Are you using ESLint?

You need to inform your linter that WebAssembly is a global object. Try adding the following to the top of the file:

```
/* global WebAssembly */
```

Although a better option might be to add it to your eslint confit file.