# ReferenceError: WebAssembly is not defined

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I'm using ttest nodejs module in application. Due to updates to it I tried to use updated version ttest@2.0.0. When module start compute data the error appears:

***ReferenceError: WebAssembly is not defined***

The NodeJS version - 6.9.1.

Error appears in next place:

```
class CephesWrapper {
  constructor(sync) {
    // Initialize the runtime's memory
    this._wasmMemory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
      'initial': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE,
      'maximum': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE
    });
.....
  }
}
```

Is there any advices about solving this issue? Is it possible to define WebAssembly?

Comment: Please, add your code to the question

Comment: Did you required/imported WebAssembly?. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015777/cant-call-webassembly-js-api-from-reactjs-component

Comment: No I didn't. I added ttest@2.0.0. This module depends on distributions@2.0.0  module which uses cephes module that calls WebAssembly.

Comment: Did you use Emscripten? Please add the emcc command you used. You did not mention any information about the toolchain, which is the most important thing to identify the problem.

Comment: I'm new to WebAssembly and I didn't use emcc command. Between this article says that code will not work on Node 6.x or Node 7.6.0 http://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-webassembly-in-node.js.html.

Comment: Oh I thought the error happened in your own code. It is a bit weird that I could not any WebAssembly-related code in ttest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebAssembly support is added in NodeJs 8.0.0. Update your NodeJS to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I was running my browser in safe mode (Mozilla Firefox).
Simply shutdown your browser completely and restart. This will quit safe mode (If stuck in safe mode, [see here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-is-stuck-in-safe-mode))

For reference, I had found this solution here : https://github.com/mozilla-iot/gateway/issues/2047

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26637277)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the advice. Maybe I didn't express myself clearly. As a matter of fact, my first paragraph is indeed the essential part of the answer I found. I provided the link just to emphasize that I didn't come up with it and to provide more context.

Comment: didn't think safe mode would have anything to do with this, thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Even my node version was 12, and npm version was 6. I was getting the reference error for webassembly.

So I updated the node with latest version(16), it changed the npm version also. Now the reference issue is fixed.

D:\ReactJS\react_demo>node -v

v16.14.0

D:\ReactJS\react_demo>npm -v

8.3.1