# How do I resolve: ReferenceError: WebAssembly is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox

I created a very simple Vue project using a single html page. I'm following a tutorial here: youtube.com/watch?v=REqu-nKek-o

The relevant code is:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue + Axios demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

My error is:

> Source map error: ReferenceError: WebAssembly is not defined Resource
>   URL: https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js Source Map URL:
>   axios.min.mapj

I have tried a few different cdn's, but I continue to get `WebAssembly is not defined`.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872019/10783877) that this was resolved in node v8. Since I am on v11, that must not be my issue.

```
$ node --version
v11.7.0
```

I see a warning that this may be a poor question. I am doing my best to ask a good question. I have researched this for several days via Internet searches. I think I simply do not have enough development experience to ask a better question at this moment, but I am open to any suggestions for improving it.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm getting this spammed into the console indefinitely....

Comment: No, I did not figure it out yet. Maybe someone will eventually reply here.

Comment: What I have found so far https://code.i-harness.com/en/docs/javascript/global_objects/webassembly/compile

Comment: @BugBuddy figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it.  I installed a newer version of nodejs:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Any version after 8.0 should work.

Took me a while to figure it out.  My error was related to bootstrap.min.css in bootstrap 4:

Source map error: ReferenceError: WebAssembly is not defined

Comment: I was already running v11.7.0 at the time I asked the question.